# Default SplashScreen showing before Extended SplashScreen

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, splash-screen, windows-store

Im trying to add a custom splashscreen on my windows 8 store app
I managed to get it to work, but the default SplashScreen still appears before my Custom one.

This is my SplashScreen XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="CartuxaTablet.ExtendedSplash"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:CartuxaTablet"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="#FF0000">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="180"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Canvas Grid.Row="0">
        <Image x:Name="extendedSplashImage" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/splash.png" Canvas.Left="158" Canvas.Top="48" />
    </Canvas>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ProgressRing IsActive="True"></ProgressRing>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and the code behind:

```
namespace CartuxaTablet
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    partial class ExtendedSplash
    {
        internal Rect splashImageRect; // Rect to store splash screen image coordinates.
        internal bool dismissed = false; // Variable to track splash screen dismissal status.
        internal Frame rootFrame;

        private SplashScreen splash; // Variable to hold the splash screen object.

        public ExtendedSplash(SplashScreen splashscreen, bool loadState)
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            // Listen for window resize events to reposition the extended splash screen image accordingly.
            // This is important to ensure that the extended splash screen is formatted properly in response to snapping, unsnapping, rotation, etc...
            Window.Current.SizeChanged += new WindowSizeChangedEventHandler(ExtendedSplash_OnResize);

            splash = splashscreen;

            if (splash != null)
            {
                // Register an event handler to be executed when the splash screen has been dismissed.
                splash.Dismissed += new TypedEventHandler<SplashScreen, Object>(DismissedEventHandler);

                // Retrieve the window coordinates of the splash screen image.
                splashImageRect = splash.ImageLocation;
                PositionImage();
            }

            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context
            rootFrame = new Frame();

            // Restore the saved session state if necessary
            RestoreStateAsync(loadState);
        }

        async void RestoreStateAsync(bool loadState)
        {
            if (loadState)
                await SuspensionManager.RestoreAsync();

            // Normally you should start the time consuming task asynchronously here and
            // dismiss the extended splash screen in the completed handler of that task
            // This sample dismisses extended splash screen  in the handler for "Learn More" button for demonstration
        }

        // Position the extended splash screen image in the same location as the system splash screen image.
        void PositionImage()
        {
            extendedSplashImage.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, splashImageRect.X);
            extendedSplashImage.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, splashImageRect.Y);
            extendedSplashImage.Height = splashImageRect.Height;
            extendedSplashImage.Width = splashImageRect.Width;
        }

        void ExtendedSplash_OnResize(Object sender, WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Safely update the extended splash screen image coordinates. This function will be fired in response to snapping, unsnapping, rotation, etc...
            if (splash != null)
            {
                // Update the coordinates of the splash screen image.
                splashImageRect = splash.ImageLocation;
                PositionImage();
            }
        }



        // Include code to be executed when the system has transitioned from the splash screen to the extended splash screen (application's first view).
        void DismissedEventHandler(SplashScreen sender, object e)
        {
            dismissed = true;

            // Navigate away from the app's extended splash screen after completing setup operations here...
            // This sample navigates away from the extended splash screen when the "Learn More" button is clicked.
        }
    }
}
```

and on my App.Xaml.cs i added this.

```
if (e.PreviousExecutionState != ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
            {
                bool loadState = (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated);
                ExtendedSplash extendedSplash = new ExtendedSplash(e.SplashScreen, loadState);
                Window.Current.Content = extendedSplash;
            }

            Window.Current.Activate();
```

Do i need to do something extra to disable the default Splash Screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable the default splash screen, but you can work with it to customize it.  You can see the [Guidelines for splash screens (Windows Store apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465338.aspx).

Comment: i followed this tutorial, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868191.aspx shouldn't my code replace the current SplashScreen? Or do i have to use both?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, your code can't replace the default one. You have to use both.